# Soma dos números menores que n que são múltiplos de 3 ou 5

Tags: algoritmo

Preciso escrever um programa que receba na entrada um número n e que imprima a soma de todos os números menores que n e que são múltiplos de 3 ou 5.

Para isso, devo usar apenas a estrutura de repetição while e nenhum tipo de dados como conjunto ou lista, pois é um exercício de um curso introdutório de programação.

Comment: Por que minha pergunta foi negativada?

Comment: Tomei a liberdade de simplificar sua pergunta para citar apenas a parte relevante: o algoritmo desejado e as restrições. Também troquei "múltiplos de 3 e 5" por "múltiplos de 3 ou 5", que acho que é o que você realmente precisa. Caso contrário, avise.

Comment: Aceito a edição.

Comment: Apenas corrigi o título.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concentre-se no fato de que a saída esperada é um único número: a soma.
Uma forma simples de resolver é olhar cada candidato, do menor até o maior. Caso ele se encaixe nas restrições, some-o a uma variável que contém o resultado parcial. Um pseudo-código que implementa essa ideia:

```
Seja n um número inteiro
Leia n
Seja soma um inteiro com valor 0
Seja i um inteiro com valor 1

Enquanto i for menor do que n:
    Se i é divisível por 3 ou i é divisível por 5:
        soma <- soma + i
    i <- i + 1

Imprima soma
```

Há espaço para otimizações. Por exemplo: é necessário olhar os números pares? E os primos? Por questão de simplicidade, deixei esse tipo de coisa fora da resposta, mas é um bom exercício pensar nisso.

Comment: Muito obrigado Pablo! Pensarei nisso com certeza!

Comment: Por nada, @GuilhermeSantanaDeSouza. Bons estudos!